# how to get Json value if Json variable contains space or any special characters in WCF

Tags: c#, json, wcf

json

```
{
 
  "id": 261111,
  "date": "2020-08-26 15:06:04",
  "ts": 1598447164,
  "message-id": "<5f462cb575dfda4548a880d4@domain.com>",
  "ts_event": 1598447164
}
```

and My Model Class is

```
class Model{

        public string id { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string message_id { get; set; }
        public string ts { get; set; }
        public string ts_event { get; set; }
}
```

and My webMethod is as below

```
public response Post(Model model)
{
  string message_Id= model.message_id;
}
```

while doing this i am getting null value for model.message_id so i have refactor my code to

```
class Model{

        public string id { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("message-id")]   //I have use newtonsoft.json 
        public string message_id { get; set; }
        public string ts { get; set; }
        public string ts_event { get; set; }
}
```

this also not working my aim is to get value (message-id) of json in web method. and to store in backend

Comment: This indeed worked for me `[JsonProperty("message-id")]`

Comment: `[JsonProperty("message-id")]` works for me with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KfDIWl working code here.

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty i am trying to implement webhook.  i saw your sample code you have use DeserializeObject but i wanted auto bind json values  to my Model class which i have pass as argument to my webMethod. thank you all of you for your quick response and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is WCF  then use DataMember attribute like this

```
[DataMember(Name = "message-id")]  
public string message_id { get; set; }
```